# How to Configure Custom Error messages with React Hook Form and Zod in Next.js?

Tags: forms, next.js, react-hook-form, zod

In my Next.js web app, I have a form as shown below:

[image]

**Note that I am using React Hook Form and Zod for schema validation**;.

Here is the code for the form:

```
"use client";

import * as z from "zod";
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { useForm } from "react-hook-form";
import { zodResolver } from "@hookform/resolvers/zod";
import { BuyCreditsFormSchema } from "@/lib/validations";
import { Icons } from "@/components/icons";
import { Button } from "@/components/ui/button";
import { Input } from "@/components/ui/input";
import { Label } from "@/components/ui/label";

export type BuyCreditsFormDataType = z.infer<typeof BuyCreditsFormSchema>;

export function BuyCreditsForm() {
  const [isBuyingCredits, setIsBuyingCredits] = useState(false);

  const {
    register,
    handleSubmit,
    formState: { errors },
  } = useForm<BuyCreditsFormDataType>({
    resolver: zodResolver(BuyCreditsFormSchema),
  });

 
  async function onBuyCredits(formData: BuyCreditsFormDataType) {
   ....
  }

  return (
    <>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onBuyCredits)}>
        <div className="space-y-6">
          <div className="grid gap-2">
            <Label htmlFor="amount" className="text-muted-foreground">
              Enter amount:
            </Label>
            <div className="grid gap-1">
              <Input
                className="bg-white"
                id="amount"
                type="number"
                placeholder="5"
                disabled={isBuyingCredits}
                {...register("amount")}
              />
              {!errors.amount && (
                <p className="px-1 text-sm text-muted-foreground">
                  Minimum amount is $1.
                </p>
              )}
              {errors.amount && (
                <p className="px-1 text-sm text-red-600 animate-in fade-in-0 slide-in-from-left-1">
                  {errors.amount.message}
                </p>
              )}
            </div>
          </div>
          <Button
            disabled={isBuyingCredits}
            type="submit"
            className="w-full rounded-md bg-blue-700 text-base hover:bg-blue-800 active:bg-blue-700"
          >
            {isBuyingCredits && (
              <Icons.spinner className="mr-2 h-4 w-4 animate-spin" />
            )}
            Buy Credits
          </Button>
        </div>
      </form>
    </>
  );
}
```

Here is the schema:

```
export const BuyCreditsFormSchema = z.object({
  amount: z.coerce.number().positive().int(),
});
```

If I don't enter any value and hit the "Buy Credits" button, I get an error message saying: `Number must be greater than 0`, as shown below:

[image]

And, if I enter a number with a decimal, I get an error message saying: `Expected intger, received float`, as shown below:

[image]

**What do I want?**

1. If I submit the form without entering any number, I want the error message to say: `Amount is required.`
2. And if I enter a number with a decimal, say 12.5, I want the error message to say: `Amount must be a whole number.`

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Check https://github.com/colinhacks/zod/blob/master/ERROR_HANDLING.md#customizing-errors-with-zoderrormap

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the message as a param:

```js
z.coerce.number({
  required_error: "Amount is required",
  invalid_type_error: "Value is not allowed please choose a valid number",
})
  .positive("Amount must be greeter than zero")
  .int("You can't use decimal numbers");
```

Not for the required_error `""` is a valid required string. empty string will not throw for required string. `coerce` will pass the result to `Number` (`Number("")` = 0) which also is a valid required. the only value that throws required_error is `undefined`.